# Reporting Services - how to represent additional data for a row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report (SSRS 2008 r2) that is used to report on enquiries made on the web site. In the data rows, I don't initially display the enquiry message due to the potential physical size of this data in the row..

So, Im thinking I need to display this message field when the row is "expanded" and it could be displayed below the main data row but full width. Im sorry if that's a little vague as Im new to Reporting Services and Im not sure how to go about this so Im looking for some suggestions on the best method to use aswell as how to implement.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table, choose detail, right click and select "Add a row below".

Merge the cells of the row and add the message field.

Select the message row (make sure you have selected the row, not the cell) and in the Visibility properties set Hidden to true and in the toggle item choose a field from the row above.

This will add an expand/collapse item on the row first row and by clicking it, it will expand and show the detail message